# Result is always zero

Tags: asp-classic

When perform this piece of code on my webserver the result is always  **<kbd>`0 (ZERO)`</kbd>**

Can anyone give a hunch on this problem (solution even better :-D )

```
Dim MyTotalPages
Dim Recordset
Dim Connection
Dim aspDBcount
Dim ShowRowCount

ShowRowCount = 3 ' Fixed size

Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}; SERVER=server_address; UID=a_username;PASSWORD=a_password; OPTION=3; Port=a_port"

Connection.Open ConnString

SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS MyRowCounts FROM `a_database`.`a_table`;"

Set Recordset = Connection.Execute(SQL)

aspDBcount = (Recordset("MyRowCounts") * 1) 

Recordset.Close

MyTotalPages = (aspDBcount * 1) / (ShowRowCount * 1))

Response.Write aspDBcount & "HTML_NEW_LINE" & ShowRowCount & "HTML_NEW_LINE" & MyTotalPages
```

> - **Output is 10, 3, 0**

- **Should be 10, 3, 3.33333...** (***with current data available in database***)

Comment: Try `aspDBcount = cInt(Recordset("MyRowCounts")) * 1`

Comment: PERFECT!!! Just what I need :D

Comment: In MySQL, `SELECT COUNT()` returns a `BIGINT` integer type and needs converting before you can use it properly in VBScript. `CInt` can only convert numbers between -32,767 and 32,767, if your `SELECT COUNT()` exceeds this range you'll need to use `CLng` instead, which has a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Comment: You can also use `CDbl`, which is a bit of a weird one. It can convert HUGE numbers and doesn't seem to have an overflow. It will just eventually return an "Invalid number" if you pass a ridiculously long integer.

Comment: All comments 'till now have been very much appreciated and gratefully received :)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit.. It's improper here to add *SOLVED* to the title or to post an answer as an edit to the question. If you want to share your solution, do so by writing an answer in the space below that is provided for that purpose. Otherwise, you can either wait and see if someone else answers, and then upvote or accept that answer, or you can delete the question itself using the link below the tags.

Comment: I’ve added my comments as an official answer if you want to mark it as correct? :)

Comment: On a side note, I’m curious to know why you’re using `*1` in your calculations?

Comment: Just an old habit from JS to insure that the var is returned as integer, float etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
aspDBcount = cInt(Recordset("MyRowCounts")) * 1
```

In MySQL, `SELECT COUNT()` returns a `BIGINT` integer type and needs converting before you can manipulate it and use it properly in VBScript.

`CInt` can only convert numbers between `-32,767` and `32,767`

If your `SELECT COUNT()` exceeds this range you'll need to use `CLng` instead, which has a range of `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`

You can also use `CDbl`, which is a bit of a weird one. It can convert **HUGE** numbers and doesn't seem to have an overflow. It will just eventually return an `Invalid number` error if you try to pass a ridiculously large integer.

Comment: You should always use `CDbl()` for `BIGINT` data type.